# How to remove agnoying 1px transparent board of LinearLayout?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-linearlayout

Have you ever noticed that actually android LinearLayout has 1px transparent board? I have a LinearLayout nested in another RelatvieLayout. And, LinearLayout aligned to the its parent's bottom. However, I still can get 1px transparent border just under the LinearLayout. Here is the image

[image: 1px transparent border under LinearLayout]

How can I remove the border? Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/gray"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/llFooter"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  style="@style/st_record_bar">
  <ToggleButton
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/btn_record_big_selector"
     android:textOn=""
     android:textOff="" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The @style/st_record_bar is defined as

```
<style name="st_record_bar">
  <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal|center</item>
  <item name="android:padding">15dip</item>
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_record_bar</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @PolamReddyRajaReddy Code is here. It is just normal RelativeLayout and LinearLayout nested.

Comment: why your using style="@style/st_record_bar" i think your getting border for this, once remove it and check again..

Comment: Pasted style definition. Tried to remove style attr. It doesn't work. I don't think anything in style definition does wrong about this.

Comment: For some reason this happened to me when I used buttons. If you can, try replacing the ToggleButton with a TextView.

Answer (score 1):

change like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="@color/gray"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/llFooter"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ToggleButton
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"

   android:textOn=""
   android:textOff="" />
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```